# Is counting sort is better than quicksort?

Tags: java, sorting

I have written a code for both counting sort and quicksort in the Java language to sort integers. Both the codes work fine for smaller inputs, but when I gave the size of the array of the order of 100,000,  the quicksort stops working whereas the counting sort sorted it correctly. So can I say that it is better to use counting sort over quicksort when the size of the unsorted array is very large? I am using Eclipse IDE Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).Thanks in advance.

Comment: Counting sort is used when you have a limited range of possible values (like if you know, that all the numbers are from 1 to 100). Quicksort is used in other cases :) Quicksort stops working - seems that you've made a mistake in implemention of it. Arrays.sort() method should work correctly

Comment: You have not presented sufficient information for a meaningful answer. Counting sort only works for a subset of the problems quicksort can solve. The correct choice depends on many other factors. If counting sort is *correct*, it is usually the best choice.

Comment: @Leo Leontev I already mentioned that both are working correctly for smaller inputs.

Comment: @Coderandhacker I added a proper answer below that illustrates the advantages of both algorithms as the dataset grows.

Comment: @Coderandhacker maybe your implementation of quick sort isn't quick :) Try searching for examples of quick sort over the Internet

Comment: @LeoLeontev here is the link to the code https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/4xPf1RwKAi

Comment: How come this is opinion based ?

Answer (score 4):

Counting sort has better time complexity but worse space complexity. So if you have very large sets it really depends on what is more important to you memory consumption or CPU consumption.

It should be noted that while counting sort is computationally superior it only applies to sorting small integer values. So while it is superior it is not always a valid replacement for Quicksort. So it is not accurate to claim that it replaces Quicksort as an option entirely.

[image]

See the following link for details: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: I think it's misleading to say that counting sort has worse space complexity: it can be worse or it can be better, depending on the relative values of N and K. I would argue that counting sort should not even be considered unless K is much, much smaller than N.

Comment: @DanielPryden fair point. Would you like to edit the answer and I will be happy to approve it.